# Can till be used for expressing distance?

Tags: prepositions, till-until

I know that till is used as a preposition  for time . 
But if  I say, " I want to trim my hair till the shoulders" 
would that be correct? If not then which preposition would be more appropriate for the given sentence?

Comment: ***We don’t use until or till to talk about distance; we use as far as:*** 

We had to drive as far as Liverpool for the last hockey match that I played.

Not: We had to drive until Liverpool … - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/until

Comment: The right preposition there would be *to*. And you could use it in *We had to drive to Liverpool ...* as well.

Answer (score 1):

As a conjunction or preposition ***'till or until / 'til'*** are used only to talk about a time point. To talk about distance, ***as far as***, or ***up to*** can be used.

> [Until as a preposition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/until)
>
> Until as a preposition means ‘up to (the time that)’:
>
> ```
> We played chess until midnight. (up to midnight)
> ```

You can trim your hair over/above/up to the shoulders, NOT till the shoulders.

[Until as a conjunction](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/until)

We use until as a subordinating conjunction to connect an action or an event to a point in time:

```
Let’s wait here till the rain stops. (till + subordinate clause)
```